# Evaluation of integral with method of stationary phase

Tags: calculus, integration, quantum-field-theory

With the integral :

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{dxF(x)\exp{(i\phi(x))}}$

The function $\phi(x)$ is a rapidly-varying function over the range of integration while $F(x)$ is a slowly-varying by comparaison.

How do we evaluate this integral using method of stationary phase ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#Other_formulations